# JSP Page not able to read/ run jquery command inside document.ready(..)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Hello Jquery/js experts

I'm currently working inside a jsp page( app type= portlet) I have a jsp file in which I put a jquery code to add some css classes and append an element inside it, this jsp is an `init.jsp page` then with `<%@ include file="init.jsp" %>` I import it in the `A.jsp page`

the problem is: This jsp not able to run code with `$('')` `sign` despite I added the cdn link to jquery like that: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` .

This is the code( plz focus on my code comments `//`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

  console.log('Im here invoking the class added event'); //this line log is well displayed in the console

 $('div#premiereConnexion .lfr-icon-item.taglib-icon').addClass('btn fistLogin btn-block'); // this line 
   //log is NOT displayed in the console
                
 console.log('****************************');//this line log is well displayed in the console

 $('div#premiereConnexion .lfr-icon-item.taglib-icon').append('<i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>');// this line log is NOT displayed in the console    
            });
</script>
```

Any one has explanation please, Thanks

Comment: where is `.lfr-icon-item.taglib-icon` ? can you add that as well in your question? Also does browser console showing any error? and does when you load your `jsp` page does that `class`  is available because here you have use `include` ?

Comment: .lfr-icon-item.taglib-icon this is the element by class which has 2 classes lfr-icon-item and taglib-icon, the problem is when I copy paste the same code in the browser it is workinh very well but it is not working inside  the jsp

Comment: can you provide of your current code ? currently its diffcult to identify error as you are saying it is working on browser but not in jsp  .